# Cannot switch to HDMI output

Tags: ati, hdmi

When I installed Ubuntu I had to disable my graphics card (Radeon 6570) and work off the integrated one because Ubuntu did not have the proper drivers for the graphics card. When I installed Ubuntu I downloaded the drivers and tried to use my Radeon 6570. The VGA port works fine, but I can't use the HDMI port, and I can't find any options to change the video output from VGA to HDMI. Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. An HDMI output should be automatically recognised and any device connected to it should receive the signal. Please check with Displays application if the external video device connected with HDMI is recognised.

Comment: When I connect the HDMI to my monitor it does recognize it, but as a different monitor. My monitor does not receive any signal though. When I try to change my monitor source, the HDMI does not show up.

Comment: With the external monitor connected, what happens if you switch it on in the Displays application?